# how to change the kubernetes default pause container download address

Tags: kubernetes

Because the network issue, I want to chang the default google pause container from official address to mirror addresss. I am trying to change the default pause container address in kubernetes `v1.28.3` like this:

```
root@k8sslave01:/var/lib/kubelet# cat /var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS="--container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --pod-infra-container-image=registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.9"
```

when I restart the kubelet service, the address seems did not work. what should I do to change the default adddress of google pause container? I also tried to add the `--pod-infra-container-image=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6`, still could not fix the issue, the kubelet log shows error:

```
root@k8sslave01:/etc/containerd# systemctl status kubelet -l --no-pager
● kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
             └─10-kubeadm.conf
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2023-11-12 00:48:39 CST; 1min 21s ago
       Docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/
   Main PID: 2436 (kubelet)
      Tasks: 10 (limit: 2025)
     Memory: 35.7M
        CPU: 1.871s
     CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
             └─2436 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --pod-infra-container-image=registry.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.9 --pod-infra-container-image=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6

Nov 12 00:49:55 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:49:55.679287    2436 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:72] "Failed to create sandbox for pod" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to do request: Head \"https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: i/o timeout" pod="reddwarf-monitor/prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-j78z6"
Nov 12 00:49:55 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:49:55.679310    2436 kuberuntime_manager.go:1166] "CreatePodSandbox for pod failed" err="rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to do request: Head \"https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: i/o timeout" pod="reddwarf-monitor/prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-j78z6"
Nov 12 00:49:55 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:49:55.679358    2436 pod_workers.go:1300] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"CreatePodSandbox\" for \"prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-j78z6_reddwarf-monitor(786d8b9f-483f-4868-a7e9-42c43997a204)\" with CreatePodSandboxError: \"Failed to create sandbox for pod \\\"prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-j78z6_reddwarf-monitor(786d8b9f-483f-4868-a7e9-42c43997a204)\\\": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to get sandbox image \\\"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\\\": failed to pull image \\\"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\\\": failed to pull and unpack image \\\"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\\\": failed to resolve reference \\\"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\\\": failed to do request: Head \\\"https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6\\\": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: i/o timeout\"" pod="reddwarf-monitor/prometheus-prometheus-node-exporter-j78z6" podUID="786d8b9f-483f-4868-a7e9-42c43997a204"
Nov 12 00:49:55 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:49:55.747517    2436 remote_runtime.go:193] "RunPodSandbox from runtime service failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to get sandbox image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to do request: Head \"https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: i/o timeout"
Nov 12 00:49:55 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:49:55.747582    2436 kuberuntime_sandbox.go:72] "Failed to create sandbox for pod" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to get sandbox image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to do request: Head \"https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: i/o timeout" pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-cvrtf"
Nov 12 00:49:55 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:49:55.747610    2436 kuberuntime_manager.go:1166] "CreatePodSandbox for pod failed" err="rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to get sandbox image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to pull and unpack image \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to resolve reference \"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\": failed to do request: Head \"https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6\": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: i/o timeout" pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-cvrtf"
Nov 12 00:49:55 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:49:55.747691    2436 pod_workers.go:1300] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="failed to \"CreatePodSandbox\" for \"kube-proxy-cvrtf_kube-system(175f3730-2bf2-4b56-8bbb-992b603edc93)\" with CreatePodSandboxError: \"Failed to create sandbox for pod \\\"kube-proxy-cvrtf_kube-system(175f3730-2bf2-4b56-8bbb-992b603edc93)\\\": rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = failed to get sandbox image \\\"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\\\": failed to pull image \\\"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\\\": failed to pull and unpack image \\\"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\\\": failed to resolve reference \\\"registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6\\\": failed to do request: Head \\\"https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/k8s-artifacts-prod/images/pause/manifests/3.6\\\": dial tcp 64.233.188.82:443: i/o timeout\"" pod="kube-system/kube-proxy-cvrtf" podUID="175f3730-2bf2-4b56-8bbb-992b603edc93"
Nov 12 00:49:57 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:49:57.053066    2436 pod_workers.go:1300] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="network is not ready: container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized" pod="calico-system/csi-node-driver-mgdpk" podUID="cf30fa63-9367-44fc-92da-9abaaec31115"
Nov 12 00:49:59 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:49:59.053229    2436 pod_workers.go:1300] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="network is not ready: container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized" pod="calico-system/csi-node-driver-mgdpk" podUID="cf30fa63-9367-44fc-92da-9abaaec31115"
Nov 12 00:50:01 k8sslave01 kubelet[2436]: E1112 00:50:01.052851    2436 pod_workers.go:1300] "Error syncing pod, skipping" err="network is not ready: container runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:Network plugin returns error: cni plugin not initialized" pod="calico-system/csi-node-driver-mgdpk" podUID="cf30fa63-9367-44fc-92da-9abaaec31115"
```

I override the containerd config `/etc/containerd/config.toml` like this:

```
[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri"]
  #sandbox_image = "k8s.m.daocloud.io/pause:3.6"
  sandbox_image = "registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6"
```

still did not fixed this issue. This is the `kubeadm-flags.env` config:

```
[root@k8s ~]# cat /var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env
KUBELET_KUBEADM_ARGS="--container-runtime-endpoint=unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock --pod-infra-container-image=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/google_containers/pause:3.6"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to apply this to your case and I don't have enough context for your error log, but generally to change the default address of the Google pause container in Kubernetes, try the following steps:

1. Edit the kubelet configuration file typically located at `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf` or `/etc/default/kubelet` depending on your setup.
2. Add or modify the `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS` line to include the `--pod-infra-container-image` flag with your desired mirror address. For example:

```bash
KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS="--pod-infra-container-image=your-mirror-address/pause:your-version"
```

Replace `your-mirror-address` with the mirror address and `your-version` with the desired version.

3. Save the changes and restart the kubelet service:

```bash
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart kubelet
```

Ensure that the mirror address is accessible and the specified version of the pause container is available at that address. This should update the pause container address for newly created pods.

If the issue persists, check the kubelet logs for any errors or warnings that might provide additional insights:

```bash
journalctl -u kubelet
```

NB. We faced a similar issue with a HostJane service deploying an application on Kubernetes and the above steps successfully changed the address of the pause container. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried this but still download the pause container from registry.k8s.io/pause:3.6, I also tried to override the address from containerd still did not fixed this error.